# How can i create responive navbar with list, javascript and @media

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive navbar with list & javascript and @media.
When i resize the browser to ~700px, the item in list style is "display: none" and the hamburger menu appears. If i don't click the hamburger menu, when i resize the browser to normal size, the list still display inline-block, but when i click the hamburger menu to display menu item in 'list-item', i still get the list-item display type when i resize my browser to normal.

Am i missing something?

```
function myFunction3() {

x = document.getElementsByClassName("li-tag");
    if (x[0].style.display === 'none'){
        for (index = 0; index<x.length; index++)
        {
            x[index].style.display = 'list-item';
        }
    } else {
        for (index = 0; index<x.length; index++)
        {
            x[index].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

}
```

My @Media

```
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .toggle-button{
        display:block;
    }

    .li-tag {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

CSS of the Navbar:

```
.tags{
    background: #0000cc;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.ul-tag {
    list-style-type:none;
    width: 70%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.li-tag {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
    font-size:25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class ="tags" >
        <a href="#" class ="toggle-button" onclick = "myFunction3()">☰</a>
        <ul class = "ul-tag">
            <li class = "li-tag "><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li class = "li-tag "><a href="#news">Type 1</a></li>
            <li class = "li-tag"><a href="#contact">Type 2</a></li>
            <li class = "li-tag "><a href="#about">Type 3</a></li>
            <li class = "li-tag "><a href="#about">Type 4</a></li>
            <li class = "li-tag "><a href="#about">Type 4</a></li>
            <li class = "li-tag "><a href="#about">Type 4</a></li>
            <li class = "li-tag "><a href="#about">Type 4</a></li>
            <li class = "li-tag "><a href="#about">Type 4</a></li>
</div>
```

My [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/w6oyphj2/)

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Don't you have option to use CSS library like bootstrap?

Comment: I can use bootstrap but i prefer do it by hand to get use to it. Maybe i can use bootstrap later if i feel comfortable with the code first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Css applied using js is an **inline rule** which has higher priority than the css rules in file.So when you set `list-item` with js , your `inline-block` rule wont work any more.
I suggest to **add a class** to your items in js and control `display`  property within the class.

JS:

```
function myFunction3() {

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("li-tag");
  for (index = 0; index<x.length; index++)
  {
    x[index].classList.toggle('list_view');
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .toggle-button{
        display:block;
    }

    .li-tag {
        display:none;
    }
    /* new */
    .li-tag.list_view{
        display: list-item;
    }

}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/op7awyxq/)

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of screens and devices with different heights and widths, so it is hard to create an exact breakpoint for each device. To keep things simple you could target five groups without using any styling library.

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Define styles spacially width, padding and margin for tags, ul-tags and li-tags in each group.